# How to prove that the distance $|x-y|$ in $A$ (where $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with positive lebesgue measure) does not belong in the Cantor set

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, cantor-set, ternary-expansion

Obviously if their distance is above 1 they don’t, but I’m curious on how to approach this for $|x-y|<1$. A thought is to prove that for this set $A$ there exist two elements $x$ and $y$ whose distance is a number that has 1 in its base 3 expansion, but I don’t know how to do that. Is there perhaps another way? I’m thinking proof by contradiction but I’m not sure…

Comment: Fix $x \in A$. If all distances in $A$ are in the Cantor set, what can you say about other $y \in A$? Which $y$ are possible?

Comment: @Tzimmo Does it have something to do with the fact that our A has a positive lebesgue measure. Meaning that there is an open interval I for which m(A$\cap$I)>0. So there must be points  x$\neq$y in A that are not in the cantor set and therefore |x-y| are not in the cantor set. Is this correct?